# AWS serverless S3 upload doesn't upload files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, serverless

I have a AWS serverless app that needs to upload files to S3. The files are not uploaded and no error is received. It's the same result when I run it locally with 'sam local' that has no S3 connection. The last line that gets printed is 'logger.debug('Uploading to S3', uploadParams);'
Why do you think no error is received?

```
async function uploadFileToS3 (fileAttributes) {
    // call S3 to retrieve upload file to specified bucket
    const uploadParams = { Bucket: bucket, Key: '', Body: '' };

    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fileAttributes.filepath);
    fileStream.on('error', (err) => {
        logger.error('File Error', err);
    });
    uploadParams.Body = fileStream;
    uploadParams.Key = fileAttributes.filename;

    logger.debug('Uploading to S3', uploadParams);
    // call S3 to retrieve upload file to specified bucket
    try {
        const stored = await s3.upload(uploadParams).promise();
        logger.info('Upload Success', stored);
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error('S3 upload error', err);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do your CloudWatch Logs tell you? Specifically, how did the Lambda function terminate? Did it time out?

Comment: are you using aws sdk? if so, use putObject https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#upload-object

Comment: @jarmod There are no errors in CloudWatch. The lambda terminates successfully, no errors, no timeout.

Comment: @Nonik It's a nodejs app, not java. The amazon examples say use upload.

Comment: @marting https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property

Comment: @Nonik It's the same with putObject.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the uploadFileToS3 was called in a forEach loop which is not promise aware.